# How to make a image auto fade in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

First time here, I've seen people put questions here and get them answered. Never seen myself coming here for help.

I would like to know how to auto fade an image on loading the website? I tried;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logo").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

But it didn't work. Logo was the same. I would like to know how to do this? Should I try div? Please help, Cheers.

Comment: http://kaidez.com/tutorial-simple-jquery-fade-in-fade-out/

Comment: Did you make sure your CSS initially hides the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `.fadeIn()` to be effective the element must be hidden beforehand.

You should put this in your CSS:

```
#logo {
    display: none;
}
```

And then run `.fadeIn()` once the page is ready.

If it's conceivable that your users might have JS disabled, then you should put this in your head tag (if you're using HTML5):

```
<noscript>
    <style>
    #logo {
        display: initial !important;
    }
    </style>
</noscript>
```